# UWP ListView: enable item reordering and tapping without selecting them

Tags: listview, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, selection, windows-10-universal

I need to provide my users with the ability to display a vertical list of items in a UWP app. The user should be able to tap items to perform some actions and to reorder them by dragging, but without the ability to select them. The UWP [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) is a good candidate for this. I would use this control with the following settings to implement what I need (a simplified form):

```xml
<ListView CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" SelectionMode="None">
    <ListViewItem>Blue</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Red</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Yellow</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Green</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Sure, in the real app I use data binding through the `ItemsSource` property and my custom item template looks like this:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Height="50" Width="50" Fill="RosyBrown" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Some text" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Unfortunately, I could not find a good and simple way to do what I need. My main problem is the selection in ListView. For instance, even if I set the ListView's `SelectionMode` to `None`, the items are still highlighted when the user is moving the mouse pointer over them. The `IsHitTestVisible` property also does not help as we can't tap and drag items if we set it to False.

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: Change the background color of selected item . Here is the link for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302146/how-to-change-highlight-color-of-the-selected-listview-item-in-uwp-windows-10

Comment: @user2354187, thank you for the tip. In my case, I needed to set the `PressedBackground`  and `PointerOverBackground` properties of the modified ListViewItem style to `Transparent`. Here is another SO topic about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321860/change-listview-item-selection-style/23547750